# Loop to count events in a time period for each user in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, dplyr

Beginner R user here. I am working with a data.frame (df1) which contains dates of studies and users who performed them. The data looks like this:

```
set.seed(42)
options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df1 <- data.frame(Date=sample(seq(as.Date('2018/01/01'), as.Date('2018/03/01'), by="day"), 10),
                  User=sample(c("Usr1","Usr2","Usr3"),10,replace=TRUE))
df1
        Date User
1  2018-02-18 Usr3
2  2018-02-06 Usr1
3  2018-01-01 Usr1
4  2018-01-25 Usr2
5  2018-01-10 Usr2
6  2018-02-05 Usr2
7  2018-01-18 Usr3
8  2018-03-01 Usr3
9  2018-02-16 Usr1
10 2018-01-24 Usr1
```

I am trying to populate another data.frame (df2) which contains a list of months and then a column for each user, such as this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(Month=seq(as.Date('2018/01/01'), as.Date('2018/03/01'), by="month"))
df2$Month <- format(df2$Month, "%Y-%m")
df2[,unique(df1$User)] <- NA

df2
    Month Usr3 Usr1 Usr2
1 2018-01   NA   NA   NA
2 2018-02   NA   NA   NA
3 2018-03   NA   NA   NA
```

I would like to create a loop function that for each user counts the number of events per month in df1 and adds this to df2, than counts the next month, and so on. So ideally the output would look something like this:

```
df2
    Month Usr3 Usr1 Usr2
1 2018-01   1    2    2
2 2018-02   1    2    1
3 2018-03   1    0    0
```

I assume that there is a neat dplyr function such as tally() that would solve this quickly but I cannot seem to be able to figure it out. Any suggestions?

Many kind thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would use a combination of dplyr and lubridate functions when working with this type of data. Lubridate contains useful functions such as month() and year() which extract the requisite elements from a date object.

In order to count the number of events I would use a group_by to select the groups we want to count by and then use the count function to tally each group.

I have attached a reprex of my code below. Please let me know if there is anything I haven't understood or that needs to be improved.

One thing I haven't included is a join between the month and year columns I have created. (@denis has provided a useful comment in this regard).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(42)
options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df1 <- data.frame(Date=sample(seq(as.Date('2018/01/01'), as.Date('2018/03/01'), by="day"), 10),
                  User=sample(c("Usr1","Usr2","Usr3"),10,replace=TRUE))

df1 %>%
  # Convert to a tibble (preference)
  tibble %>% 
  # convert the date to a month and a year as these are the only necessary components
  # Additionally this makes it simpler to group by month
  mutate(year = year(Date), month = month(Date, label = T)) %>% 
  # Create groupings of the things we want to tally
  group_by(month, year, User) %>% 
  # Count the members of each group
  count() %>% 
  # Rearrange the dataframe into the requisite format
  pivot_wider(names_from = User, values_from = n)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#> # Groups:   month, year [3]
#>   month  year  Usr1  Usr2  Usr3
#>   <ord> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 Jan    2018     2     2     1
#> 2 Feb    2018     2     1     1
#> 3 Mar    2018    NA    NA     1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: use `format.Date(ymd(df1$Date),"%Y-%m")` to have the OA `month` variable

Answer (score 1):

Base R option :

```
table(transform(df1, Date = format(Date, '%Y-%m')))

#       User
#Date      Usr1 Usr2 Usr3
#  2018-01    2    2    1
#  2018-02    2    1    1
#  2018-03    0    0    1
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like Ronak Shah's answer because it is a simple short line of base R code. If you want to stay in the tidyverse there are two more options beside the `count` / `pivot_wider` approach to create columns.

You could use `purrr::map_dfc` in a grouped `summarise` call. You would need to set up the names of the vector (`unique` values of `User`) you want to loop over first. Then you can use `sum(User == .x)` to get the count of each instance of `User` as column.

Another options is `over` (disclaimer: its part of a package I created that makes creating columns by looping over vectors and / or sets of columns easier). In this case you can just use `over` in a grouped  `summarise` call instead of `map_dfc`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# map_dfc
library(purrr)
user_vec <- df1$User %>% unique() %>% set_names(.,.)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(month = format.Date(ymd(Date),"%Y-%m")) %>% 
  summarise(map_dfc(user_vec, ~ sum(User == .x)))

#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   month    Usr3  Usr1  Usr2
#>   <chr>   <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 2018-01     1     2     2
#> 2 2018-02     1     2     1
#> 3 2018-03     1     0     0

# over
library(dplyover) # https://github.com/TimTeaFan/dplyover

df1 %>% 
  group_by(month = format.Date(ymd(Date),"%Y-%m")) %>% 
  summarise(over(dist_values(User), ~ sum(User == .x)))

#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   month    Usr1  Usr2  Usr3
#>   <chr>   <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 2018-01     2     2     1
#> 2 2018-02     2     1     1
#> 3 2018-03     0     0     1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>